# finding smallest and second smallest number

Tags: java, loops

This program is supposed to find the smallest and the second smallest number among x numbers. 
The program finds the smallest number every time, but I have problems replacing the second smallest number from the keyboard.

```
 System.out.println("How many numbers?");
 int total = keyboard.nextInt();

 System.out.println("What is the first number");
 int small = keyboard.nextInt();

 System.out.println("whats the second number");
 int nest = keyboard.nextInt();
 // Assigning the first two numbers to smallest and second largest

 for (int i =2;i<total;i++) {                     
    System.out.println("whats the next number?");
    int number = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (number < small) {
       small = number;
    } // this part works (I think)

    if ((number > small) && (number < nest)) {
       nest = number;
    }//this part dont (I think)

 }//end forloop
 System.out.printf("The smallest numbers are %d and %d",small,nest);
```

Comment: @shekharsuman What is the point in making them static? Add all the numbers to a `LinkedList` sort the `List` in ascending order, take the first two items in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to get the order right. First, see if the number is smaller than the smallest number, and if so, replace it and move the old smallest number to the second smallest number. Else, if it is smaller than the second smallest number, replace that.

Here's the code that should be in the loop:

```
if (number < small) {
    nest = small;
    small = number;
} else if (number < nest) {
    nest = number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all the numbers to a `LinkedList<Integer>` then sort the `List`.  The first two items in the `List` will be the smallest.

```
public class Sorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("How many numbers?");
        int total = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("What is the first number");
        numbers.add( keyboard.nextInt());
        System.out.println("whats the second number");
        numbers.add( keyboard.nextInt());
        // Assigning the first two numbers to smallest and second largest

        for (int i =2;i<total;i++) {                     
        System.out.println("whats the next number?");
        numbers.add( keyboard.nextInt());
        }//end forloop

        Collections.sort(numbers);

        System.out.printf("The smallest numbers are %d and %d",numbers.get(0),numbers.get(1)); 

    }
}
```

Comment: I have to import  Scanner to get this to work, anything else I need to do? I get : List cannot be resolved to type error?

Comment: @user2938 Import `java.util.List`

Answer (score 0):

here is the code:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      int secondMin=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      while (console.hasNextInt())
      {
         int x = console.nextInt();
         if (x < min) {
           secondMin=min;
             min = x;
           } else if (x <secondMin && x!=min)
          secondMin=x;        
                
      }
      System.out.println(secondMin);

          }
      }
```

You need to make sure to add **x!=min** to the "**else if**" condition. If this condition is not passed and the smallest number is entered twice it will be assigned to secondMin