# Smallest and second smallest in an array

Tags: java, sorting

I've looked at the answer posted here ([finding smallest and second smallest number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700887/finding-smallest-and-second-smallest-number)) but I cannot get my code to work.

Here is what I have.

```
    public static void shortestTimes(int[] times){

    int counter = 0;
    int secondLowest = times[counter];
    int min = times[counter];

    for (counter = 0; counter < times.length; counter ++) {

        if (times[counter] < min) {
            secondLowest = min;
            min = times[counter];

    } else if (times[counter] < secondLowest) {
        secondLowest = times[counter];
    }
}

System.out.println("The fastest time was: " + min + ". And the second fastest was: " + secondLowest);   
}
```

When I put in the input:

```
int[] values = {1, 3, 3, 2, 5};
longestTimes(values);
```

I get the output:

```
The fastest time was: 1. And the second fastest was: 1
```

Why is my second lowest number not getting changed?

Comment: Personally, I'd sort the array, but you might not be allowed to...

Comment: Considering there are no numbers smaller the `1` in the array (which is also the first element), the `secondLowest` can never be assigned any other value.  Try initialising `secondLowest` and `min` with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead

Comment: You initialize both `secondLowest` and `min` to the first number in the array.  If the first number in the array is the smallest, those two variables will never get set to anything else.  You'll need to fix the initialization.  I think the rest of your logic is OK.

Comment: Take a look at the initial values for `min` and `secondLowest`... with your example, is there any way any number will ever be less than that?

Comment: if you set the initial values to `High` values then the logic will get entered into, but as you have it, the values are set to `1` (value of time[0]) and so no more values are `<` than this

Comment: Humm...i see i see...it was the initial values given that would not let the rest of the code change. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second lowest value is not getting changed because from the beginning you are setting `secondLowest` to be equal to the value at values[0], which is your lowest value in the array.  If I were you, I would initialize both `min` and `secondLowest` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  Then the algorithm would behave as expected

Answer (score 0):

Firstly when you declare `min` and `secondLowest` I would check if `times.length >= 2`.

I would then assign them with:

```
min = times[0];
secondLowest = times[1];
```

The problem is with your declaration of `secondLowest` and the fact that they both start at the lowest value. You don't have any sort of check to see if `min` and `secondLowest` are referring to the same number within the array.

If the array is guaranteed to contain unique values this isn't an issue, but if not you should change around your search. Sorting the array would help too.

Comment: so what would happen if times[1] is also `1` ?

Comment: Then the output would be correct. If there were two `1` values. Then they would occupy both the first and second smallest value. That is why in my answer I addressed whether or not your array guarantees unique values. If not, and you want `secondLowest` to be `2` or whatever when there are two `1` values within the array, you will need to change they way you search.